# problem while initiating page from jekyll through github

Tags: github, jekyll

I currently succeed in establishing my page through github with jekyll
and the url is this: https://youngkyonyou.github.io/YoungKyonYou.github.io/
but whenever I go into the category and click one of it
it suddenly shows 404 error and I'm having trouble how to fix this.
my repo is this: https://github.com/YoungKyonYou/YoungKyonYou.github.io
can somebody help me with it? 
[image: the category page]

and whenever I click one of it the problem occurs 
[image: and whenever i click one of it the problem occurs]

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out~
I dunno y but after erasing the baseurl from config.yml
it was solved...
kinda weird... I thought